# Create an array of times with 15 minute interval (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, time, intervals

I'm new to programming and having a hard time coming up with an efficient way to create an array of times without typing out the entire array in swift.

I would like to dynamically create an array of the form:

```
["5:00","5:30", (...), "22:00"]
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
var timeSlots = [Double]()
var firstTime: Double = 5
var lastTime: Double = 22 // 10pm
var slotIncrement = 0.5
var numberOfSlots = Int((lastTime - firstTime) / slotIncrement)

var i: Double = 0
while timeSlots.count <= numberOfSlots {
    timeSlots.append(firstTime + i*slotIncrement)
    i += 1
}

print(timeSlots) // [5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0, 8.5, 9.0, 9.5, 10.0, 10.5, 11.0, 11.5, 12.0, 12.5, 13.0, 13.5, 14.0, 14.5, 15.0, 15.5, 16.0, 16.5, 17.0, 17.5, 18.0, 18.5, 19.0, 19.5, 20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5, 22.0]
```

The time interval portion is important because I would like to be able to create an array with 15 minute times slots, 10 minute time slots, etc.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show more code. There is not enough detail about the specific programming problem, and it's unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to multiply your time slots elements by 60 to convert your number of hours to minutes and use `DateComponentsFormatter` using `.positional` unitsStyle to convert the `TimeInterval` (seconds) to `String`:

```
let dateComponentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .positional

let times = timeSlots.flatMap{dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: $0 * 60)}
print(times)  // ["5:00", "5:30", "6:00", "6:30", "7:00", "7:30", "8:00", "8:30", "9:00", "9:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30", "15:00", "15:30", "16:00", "16:30", "17:00", "17:30", "18:00", "18:30", "19:00", "19:30", "20:00", "20:30", "21:00", "21:30", "22:00"]
```

Note that the result means actually minutes and seconds but the string representation it is exactly what you want.

---

Another option is to use `String(format:)` initializer and create a custom format to convert your number of hours as follow:

```
extension Double {
    var hours2Time: String {
        return String(format: "%02d:%02d", Int(self), Int((self * 60).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)))
        // or formatting the double with leading zero and no fraction
        // return String(format: "%02.0f:%02.0f", rounded(.down), (self * 60).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
    }
}
```

---

```
let times2 = timeSlots.map{ $0.hours2Time }
print(times2)  // // ["05:00", "05:30", "06:00", "06:30", "07:00", "07:30", "08:00", "08:30", "09:00", "09:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30", "15:00", "15:30", "16:00", "16:30", "17:00", "17:30", "18:00", "18:30", "19:00", "19:30", "20:00", "20:30", "21:00", "21:30", "22:00"]
```

Comment: Just voting a 6 months old answer (accepted)  down without a comment won't help you and or the original poster. If you let me know what's wrong (is it?) with my answer I can try to improve it if possible.

Comment: I want to create the time slots like [09:00 - 09:30, 09:15 - 09:45, 09:30 - 10:30]. 30 minutes slots and 15 minutes gap.

Answer (score 3):

```
var timeArray: [String] = []
let firstTime: Double = 5
let lastTime: Double = 22 // 10pm
var currentTime: Double = 5
var incrementMinutes: Double = 15 // increment by 15 minutes

while currentTime <= lastTime {
    currentTime += (incrementMinutes/60)
    let hours = Int(floor(currentTime))
    let minutes = Int(currentTime.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)*60)
    if minutes == 0 {
        timeArray.append("\(hours):00")
    } else {
        timeArray.append("\(hours):\(minutes)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar need. This was my solution, but it only works with minute intervals of:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, and 60.

I didn't have a start or stop time requirement, but they can be adjusted by

changing `0`  - `24` in `for h in 0..<24 {`.

```
var timeArray: [String] = []
    
let interval = 15
    
for h in 0..<24 {
    for m in 0..<(60/interval) {
        if m * interval == 0 {
            timeArray.append("\(String(format: "%02d", h))00")
        } else {
            timeArray.append("\(String(format: "%02d", h))\(String(format: "%02d", m * interval))")
        }
    }
}
    
print(timeArray)
```

Output:

> ["0000", "0015", "0030", "0045", "0100", "0115", "0130", "0145",
> "0200", "0215", "0230", "0245", "0300", "0315", "0330", "0345",
> "0400", "0415", "0430", "0445", "0500", "0515", "0530", "0545",
> "0600", "0615", "0630", "0645", "0700", "0715", "0730", "0745",
> "0800", "0815", "0830", "0845", "0900", "0915", "0930", "0945",
> "1000", "1015", "1030", "1045", "1100", "1115", "1130", "1145",
> "1200", "1215", "1230", "1245", "1300", "1315", "1330", "1345",
> "1400", "1415", "1430", "1445", "1500", "1515", "1530", "1545",
> "1600", "1615", "1630", "1645", "1700", "1715", "1730", "1745",
> "1800", "1815", "1830", "1845", "1900", "1915", "1930", "1945",
> "2000", "2015", "2030", "2045", "2100", "2115", "2130", "2145",
> "2200", "2215", "2230", "2245", "2300", "2315", "2330", "2345"]